# how to use a cell value in an active column in a named row range in VBA

Tags: vba, range, named

In a worksheet, there are two named ranges, each of which only contains a row, e.g. Range1 = Range("B5:H5") and Range2 = Range("B9:H9"). My question is: how can I reference a cell in Range1, say C5, and a cell in Range2, say C9 in VBA so that I can do something with the values in these two cells? The VBA should only run for the active column. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should see this link.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

As Siddarth stated,

Two Main reasons why .Select/.Activate/Selection/Activecell/Activesheet/Activeworkbook etc... should be avoided

```
It slows down your code.
It is usually the main cause of runtime errors.
```

How do we avoid it?

1) Directly work with the relevant objects

Consider this code

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Value = "Blah"
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

This code can also be written as

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .Value = "Blah"
    .NumberFormat = "@"
End With
```

2) If required declare your variables. The same code above can be written as

```
Dim ws as worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws.Range("A1")
    .Value = "Blah"
    .NumberFormat = "@"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can

```
Range1.offset()
```

method to refer adjacent cell

You can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-offset-property-excel) for detail .

Comment: Thanks, KNVB. I would like to use the range names rather than Offset in case a user changes the spreadsheet layout. I can use: variable1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Row(5) and variable2 = ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Row(9), but this does not use the named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Range("Range1").Cells(1, 1).Select     'Selects Range("B5") - first cell in Range1
Range("Range1").Cells(1, "A").Select   'Also selects first cell in the named range

'copies cell 2 (C9) from Range2 into cell 2 (C5) of Range1; .Cells(row, col)
Range("Range1").Cells(1, 2) = Range("Range2").Cells(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Cells` method, you can specify the appropriate row using `Range1.Row` (and `Range2.Row`), and the appropriate column using (if I understand you correctly) `Selection.Column`.

So perhaps something like:

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Range2 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("B5:H5")
Set Range2 = Range("B9:H9")

'Display the value in row 5 for the current column
MsgBox Cells(Range1.Row, Selection.Column).Value
'Display the value in row 9 for the current column
MsgBox Cells(Range2.Row, Selection.Column).Value

'Change row 9 to be the value from row 5
Cells(Range2.Row, Selection.Column).Value = Cells(Range1.Row, Selection.Column).Value

'Display the updated value in row 9 for the current column
MsgBox Cells(Range2.Row, Selection.Column).Value
```